# Example for Google Endpoint with Hibernate over Cloud SQL

Tags: hibernate, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-endpoints

Does Google Endpoints work with Hibernate over Cloud SQL? 
Can some post a short code example for it? 
I tried to do so and encountered in general errors while generating a client library

Language Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LANGUAGES")
public class Language  {

private String languageIsoCode;
private String languageName;

public Language() {}

@Id
@Column(name = "LANGUAGE_ISO_CODE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 8)
public String getLanguageIsoCode() {
    return this.languageIsoCode;
}

public void setLanguageIsoCode(String languageIsoCode) {
    this.languageIsoCode = languageIsoCode;
}

@Column(name = "LANGUAGE_NAME", nullable = false, length = 160)
public String getLanguageName() {
    return this.languageName;
}

public void setLanguageName(String languageName) {
    this.languageName = languageName;
}
}
```

LanguageEndpoint Class:

```
@Api
public class LanguageEndpoint {

@ApiMethod
public String getLanguage(){
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    Query q = mgr.createQuery("from Language");
    Language l = (Language) q.getResultList().get(0);
    return l.getLanguageName();
}

private static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return EMF.hibernateGet().createEntityManager();
}

}
```

and EMF class:

```
public final class EMF {
private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

private static final EntityManagerFactory emfHibernateInstance = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory("com.google.cloudsql.jpa");

private EMF() {
}

public static EntityManagerFactory get() {
    return emfInstance;
}

public static EntityManagerFactory hibernateGet() {
    return emfHibernateInstance;
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you tried and we'll try to help. Cloud Endpoints runs on App Engine, so you can do anything in a Cloud Endpoints method that you could do anywhere else in App Engine.

Comment: posted the code. I would appreciate if you look at it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. 
First of all, the eclipse plugin just writes that it has encountered errors when you try to generate endpoint library, you call always use the good old scripts in the sdk (endpoints.cmd) and get the full log.

This is what I saw in the log:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManager"

The problem was that despite removing Datanucleus from the project, it seems that some features collide in it's jars and those of Hibernate. 
So instead of using the standard JPA EMF I turned to HibernateUtil and SessionFactory.

Another problem was that apparently String can not be used as a return value for an API.